# How to rewrite Uni<List<Fruit>> to Multi without a list? Reactive Programming

Tags: mongodb, reactive-programming, quarkus, mutiny, smallrye

As i am working in a Project where i want to rewrite the Uni to Multi for a method "findall" to get all the mongodb Document from a collection. I tried to rewrite but not able to find a solution

original:

```
public Uni<List<Book>> findAll(List<String> authors)
    {

        return getCollection().
                find(Filters.all("authors",authors)).map(Book::from).collectItems().asList();
}
```

What i tried (But not working)

```
public Multi<Book> findAll(List<String> authors)

        {
    return getCollection().find(Filters.all("authors",authors)).transform().
                    byFilteringItemsWith(Objects::nonNull).onCompletion().ifEmpty().
                    failWith(new NoSuchElementException("couldn't find the Authors")).onItem().transform(Book::from);
    }
```

Comment: Do you use MongoDB with Panache ? If so, there is a `stream`  method that returl a Multi and not a Uni<List>.

Comment: First of all thanks a lot. Nope. We don't use Panache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you are using the `ReactiveMongoClient` provided by Quarkus.
In this case, your method should be:

```java
ReactiveMongoClient client;

public ReactiveMongoCollection<Book> getCollection() {
    return client.getDatabase("db").getCollection("books", Book.class);
}

public Multi<Book> findAll(List<String> authors) {
    return getCollection()
            .find(Filters.all("authors",authors))
            .onItem().transform(Book::from)
            .onCompletion().ifEmpty()
                 .failWith(new NoSuchElementException("..."));

}
```

You don't need to do the`byFilteringItemsWith`, as a `Multi` cannot contain `null` items.